# How to use Group by and Order by in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to linq and do not understand how to use the group by or order by, and when using the Distinct, you have no ability to order by. 
This is the SQL I would like to convert to LINQ:

```
SELECT enrStaff.LastName, enrStaff.FirstName, enrStaff.MiddleInit, enrStaff.FaNo
FROM   usrUserBldgList INNER JOIN
   entEntity ON usrUserBldgList.EntID = entEntity.EntID INNER JOIN
   enrStaff ON entEntity.FANo = enrStaff.FaNo
WHERE     (usrUserBldgList.UserID = Param1)
GROUP BY enrStaff.LastName, enrStaff.FirstName, enrStaff.MiddleInit, enrStaff.FaNo
```

This is what I tried in LINQ but the list can not be ordered by

```
(From sl In _db.Staffs _
      Join e In _db.Entities On e.FANo Equals sl.FaNo _
      Join ubl In _db.UserBldgLists On ubl.EntID Equals e.EntID _
      Where (ubl.UserID = Param1) _
      Select sl).Distinct()
```

This is what I tried for a grouping, that gave me an IQueryable error

```
(From ubl In _db.UserBldgLists _
  Join e In _db.Entities On e.EntID Equals ubl.EntID _
  Where ubl.EntID = Param1 _
  Group Join sl In _db.Staffs On e.FANo Equals sl.FaNo _  
  Into staffers = Group _
  Select staffers)
```

I would appreciate it if someone can point out how to get the LINQ group to give me a single result of the Staff table, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `Group Join`? Are you sure about that syntax?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that's how you do a `GroupJoin` in VB. (`join ... into` in C#)

Comment: What do you mean " can not be ordered by"?

Comment: I am unable to get an Order by statement in the query that will order the results by lastname, firstname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your SQL is not doing any aggregations it's effectively getting a distinct list of values in the grouping criteria, so your first query should work.

<strike>Your original query does not do any ordering so it's unclear what you're trying to do after that.</strike>

To add ordering you can either add it to the query-syntax part:

```
(From sl In _db.Staffs _
      Join e In _db.Entities On e.FANo Equals sl.FaNo _
      Join ubl In _db.UserBldgLists On ubl.EntID Equals e.EntID _
      Where (ubl.UserID = Param1) _
      Order By sl.LastName, sl.FirstName _
      Select sl).Distinct()
```

Or using Linq-to-Objects after the fact:

```
(From sl In _db.Staffs _
      Join e In _db.Entities On e.FANo Equals sl.FaNo _
      Join ubl In _db.UserBldgLists On ubl.EntID Equals e.EntID _
      Where (ubl.UserID = Param1) _
      Order By sl.LastName, sl.FirstName
      Select sl).Distinct() _
      .OrderBy(Function(o) o.LastName) _
      .ThenBy(Function(o) o.FirstName)
```

Comment: I want this query to provide me a list of names that do not have a repeating value that is ordered by the lastname and firstname.

Comment: I have added the code as suggested above and the list is still unsorted  (From sl In _db.Staffs _
                        Join e In _db.Entities On e.FANo Equals sl.FaNo _
                        Join ubl In _db.UserBldgLists On ubl.EntID Equals e.EntID _
                        Where (ubl.UserID = Param1)
                        Order By sl.LastName, sl.FirstName _
                        Select sl).Distinct()

Comment: Try ordering after the distinct.  The Linq provider you're using may not keep the original order when you call Distinct (Linq-to-SQL does this I think).